# Get UserId of Facebook user

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a snippet where I allow a user on my MVC Asp.net Site to publish a POST. It works fine.

What I need is when the POST is published and a facebook user clicks on it (There is a url action that takes you to mywebsite if the user clicks on it) . How would I get the userId or something indicating it was clicked by XXXX facebook user?

Once a user on my site publishes this post, a friend may click on the link and I want to know what user clicked on it.

```js
    function facebookShare()

    {

        FB.ui({

            method: 'feed',

            name: "My gallery - Price: $49.99",

            link: "https://mygallery.net/Product/Details/99",

            picture: "http://mygallery.com//Images/Products/image.jpg",

            description: "In the last 100 years of....",

            caption: "Product Name: Awesome Pix-X",

            quote:"Quote: You will always be mine!"

        },

 

        function (response)

        {

            if (response && !response.error_message) {

                alert('post_id : ' + response.post_id);

            } else {

                alert('Error while posting.');

            }

 

        });

 

    }
```

So Do I add a query parameter in here to dynamically get facebook user who clicks on it?
link: "https://mygallery.net/Product/Details/99",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user did not authorize your App, there is no way to know. If he authorized your App, you can get his id with `FB.getLoginStatus`, for example.

Comment: Ok. I thought you could dynamically add the userid to the link. Well I am able to use FB.getLoginStatus to check if user has authorized app. If not then I display the FB.login function.